# TortoiseGit not working on WSL filesystem

Tags: git, tortoisegit

From within WSL2, I cloned same repo to two locations: `/home/user/work` and `/mnt/c/work/`

Then, `Right-click > TortoiseGit > Settings > Git > Remote`.
The repo on my `C:\` gives no errors but the one accessed from `\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\` gives an error.

**QUESTION**
Is the possible to fix this?

[image: TortoiseGit]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in TortoiseGit 2.14.0.0.

A fixed version 2.4.0.1 is available for [download](https://tortoisegit.org/download/).